# construct circle defined by point, radius and enclosed & touched circle

Tags: geometry, circles

If this can easily be derived from an already answered question please be so kind to point me there. I tried but couldn't find an equivalent problem.

I have one circle $D$ with the origin as center fully defined by its radius $r_D$.
I have a given point $P$ which is outside $D$.

Now I want to construct a circle $H$ with known radius $r_H > r_D$, such that $P$ is on the circle and $D$ is enclosed inside $H$ and $H$ is touching $D$.

Where is the circle center of $H$/how do I calculate the point where $D=H$?

There are two solutions (though I just need one).

Comment: connect center of $D$ (let's say point $O$) with $P$. Now draw a perpendicular to $OP$ that goes thru $O$. The perpendicular $OA$ will intersect $D$ at two points $A$ and $B$ (hence two solutions). Triange $OPA$ is a right triangle. Find $\angle{OPA}$. Construct angle equal to $90-2 \cdot OPA$ that has $P$ as vertex and $OP$ as one of the sides (again, there are two ways to construct the angle, choose wisely), The other side of the angle will intersect line $OA$  at some point, that point will be the center of $H$.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your suggestion. The circle center of $H$ cannot be on the line $OA$ though. Your suggestion sets $r_H=3*r_D$ (if I'm not mistaken) but the radius $r_H$ is actually known and fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $H$ must touch (i.e. not intersect) $D$. This means it's center is located on a circle around the center of $D = (0,0)$ with the radius $r_H - r_D$. Simultaniously it must be on a circle with radius $r_D$ with center $P$. 
Now your problem is reduced to finding the intersection points of two circles.

Say: $(c_x,c_y)$ is the center of $H$ and wlog $P = (P_x,0)$.
You have the equations:
$$
c_x^2+c_y^2 = (r_D - r_H)^2 \text{ and } (c_x - P_x)^2+c_y^2 = r_H^2
$$
The rest should be simple, i guess.

Comment: This is a beautifully simple solution that none of the 5 people I asked came up with. Props!

Comment: Glad i could help!